# Can't Connect to MariaDB from Basic PHP Script

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to learn how to make mysql queries, using MAMP, MariaDB, and 2 PHP scripts.

I used MYSQL Workbench to make a schema (helloWorld), added a table (Paintings), and put 2 entries in the table.  I created a 'shuwoo'@'localhost' user, and granted all permissions to it, using the terminal.  I successfully logged into MYSQL Workbench, but when I looked at shuwoo's "Administrative Roles", "DBA", "SecurityAdmin", and "DBManager" are unchecked.  Trying to enable them in the Workbench gives me an error.

The real issue is that my php script gives me an error, "Could not connect: Access denied for user 'shuwoo'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" when I run the script.  The code is very simple, here it is:

Note: I've noticed it doesn't matter what I enter for mysql_select_db.  I think that's because I'm not even getting access to this level?

Your help is greatly appreciated!

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost:3306';
$dbuser = 'shuwoo';
$dbpass = 'Poptart5';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM Paintings';

mysql_select_db('helloWorld');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo "ID :{$row['Id']}  <br> ".
         "Title: {$row['Title']} <br> ".
         "Description: {$row['Description']} <br> ".
         "Medium: {$row['Medium']} <br> ".
         "--------------------------------<br>";
} 
echo "Fetched data successfully";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but **STOP USING mysql_* functions** They have been removed from the latest version of php and have been depreciated for a log time before that. Use `PDO` instead. If you are following a tutorial that uses `mysql_` stop, its seriously out of date, or just plain bad

Comment: You shouldn't need those roles just to establish a connection. And you are correct that it's not even getting to `mysql_select_db`. Your script has died before it reaches that point.

Comment: The first thing I would suggest is to re-verify that your username and password are truly correct. It's one of the simplest solutions to a connection error, so it's worth double checking, even if you're already certain they're correct.

Comment: This MySQL troubleshooting guide may be helpful ( [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/problems-connecting.html) ), particularly the section regarding password changes.

Comment: Sounds like the password is wrong.

Comment: Big thanks for the advice on mysql_ functions.  I had no clue.  I just created another database, table, entries, and a new user.  I granted all permissions to the new user.  I got the same error when I was ready.  I'm sure that I set my sample password to "Poptart5".  Really not sure what's going on at this point.  Could MAMP's built in MySQL server be a problem?  It's on port 8889, and MariaDB is on 1303.

Comment: Well if your mariadb is Listening on port 1303 then this line is wrong `$dbhost = 'localhost:3306';` it should be `$dbhost = 'localhost:1303';`

Comment: Try this on the mysql console: `grant all privileges on helloWorld.* to 'shuwoo'@'localhost' with grant option;` and then `flush privileges;`